# Create user with multiple IP address in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

I am using mysql workbench 5.5 to access a remote server. via mysql workbench I was created the user `sms` who can access the DB by only one host IP address.But, Now I want to create a user who should access the DB from 2 IP addresses. I was insert the IP address like this `10.103.1.32/10.103.1.166`. After this the first IP address `10.103.1.32` is not able to connct the DB

Comment: Are you referring to granting mysql user rights rather than a self imposed restriction?

Comment: @BugFinder I need to create a user can connect the DB from particular 2 hosts only

Comment: As I said, are you using the mysql grant user permissions or, is this going to be done from your own code?

Comment: @BugFinder I'll do this by grant user permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update old record, like this

```
UPDATE tableName
   SET IP =  CONCAT(IP, '/', 'newIP')
WHERE  userID = valueHere
```

But it is going to be a bad table design, best way is to create a separate table for the IP of  a certain user, like this simple schema

```
CREATE TABLE userList
(
   ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
   User_Name VARCHAR(50,
   -- other columns
   CONSTRAINT use_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE user_IP
(
    RecordID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserID INT,
    IPADDRESS VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT ip_pk PRIMARY KEY (RecordID),
    CONSTRAINT ip_uq UNIQUE(UserID, IPADDRESS),
    CONSTRAINT ip_fk FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES userList(ID)
)
```